# SQL for sum of all "children"

Tags: sql, group-by, sum

Doing a table for budget accounts, my hierarchy is stored in a "path" column like so:

- groceries.produce.vegetables.tomatoes
- groceries.produce.vegetables.potatoes
- groceries.produce.fruit
- groceries.baking.flour
- etc

Works great when I need to grab all produce because I can just do a

> LIKE 'produce.%'

query and get anything beneath it in the tree.

However, for any given query, I would like to have a "total" column to sum up prices of all records "beneath".

The only way I can think of is to do a pattern match on a GROUP BY, but I have a hunch I may be going down the wrong path.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select sum(prices)
        from t t2
        where t2.path like t.path || '.%'
       ) as SumBeneath
from t;
```

One thing.  The `'.%'` is to get everything beneath, excluding the current row from t.  If you want the current row included, remove the period.